# How can I reduce the Largest Contentful Paint overhead of Magento 2 cookie restriction mode?

Tags: magento2.3, pagespeed-insights, allow-cookie

Our Google Pagespeed Insights score is suffering due to Largest Contentful Paint when using the Magento 2.3.0 default cookie restriction mode popup. With cookie restriction mode enabled the LCP is showing at over 7 seconds for mobile, the score is close to 3 seconds with cookie restriction disabled (some further minor changes will get LCP below 3s, to the 'good' Pagespeed level).

Can anyone suggest how I can reduce the system overhead of the default cookie popup please? For example, can it be preloaded or loaded earlier in the page? Are there any 3rd party extensions which are known to perform much better than the default cookie popup? Would a Magento version upgrade (=> 2.4) help?

Hoping for good news. Thanks...